# Apache virtualhost is showing always the default page

Tags: debian, apache-http-server

I have a Debian Jessie VPS server I want to host 3 Wordpress sites on it.
I have already modify the virtualhost for the first site `www.exemplesite1.com` (`/var/www/html/wordpress1`)and it is working. Now I want to add the second site. I create the folder in `/var/www/html/wordress2` and create the virtualhost file  for the second site `www.examplesite2.com`. But when I try to reach `www.exemplesite2.com` I get the Apache default page and if use the IP adress of my server it works.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName exemplesite2.com
    ServerAlias www.exemplesite2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/wordpress2
    Redirect permanent /phpmyadmin https://xxxxxxx.ovh.net/phpmyadmin
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/html/wordpress2>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
      ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Comment: `ServerAlias www.exemplesite2.com` contains a spelling error.

Comment: yes. i correct it.

Comment: Well did you restart the server? Did it fix the problem?

Comment: yes i have restarted the server but i steel getting the default page. i use the ip_adresse/wp-admin to login in the dashbord of wordpress and change it with the general configuration. but when i change the site url i get 404 error.

Comment: `ServerName exemplesite2.com` is wrong as well.

Comment: "I create the folder in `/var/www/html/wordress2`" and this is also wrong.

Comment: thank you for i correct it in my configuration but it still remain. i can t solve it. the virtualhost works for just for one site.